# ExtJs Combo display field

Tags: extjs

I have a some combos on window , I had set `valuefield : DID` and `displayfield` as *Name* and set `dataIndex` Property as `ID` ,problem is some times its display name and some times display `Id`.

So how to set only name as displayed (dataIndex).

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

if you see an ID instead of name, there is two possibility

- store isn't loaded yet.
- given ID not found in the store